# common android sdk platform

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-2.2-froyo

Just have a question regarding which platform to use or which is the most commonly used sdk platform for development?

I am preparing an application which has a location finder using google maps, and the primary target of client is to make it run on most of the android phones. I was thinking to go with google api 2.2 platform 8, would it be good?

## EDIT - 1

Thanks for the information guys, but when looking at android platform distribution page here:
http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html
I get a feel that why not i should go for 2.3.3? any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the current [Android Platform Version distribution here](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html).
It's a living updated document/page, so keep an eye on it over a period of time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the platform as google api 2.2. As the app deployed will be compatible with all higher versions.

Also the market share is as follows:[Android OS market Share](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html)

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use 2.2, because from 2.2 only the android was picking up... And it supplies your requirements also...